# Define Record key as partial based on literal type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The main idea is to get an accurate implementation of the swap methods in all dex abstract classes which I have.

I had tried to implement it as this:

```js
// This is union outputs type for each swap method handler for UniswapV2Router abstract class
// As different dexes would have different returnings in swap handlers
// In future it might be extended with other such types for different dexes
type FinderOutput = UniswapV2MethodOutput; 

// This type specifies method names with swap handlers in abstract classes, now it more general one
// Also I want to make it more specific in future, that it could be possible to indentify swap method type by a method name in someway 
type ContractMethodImplementations = Record<string, (...args: any[]) => Promise<FinderOutput>>;

// This type describes names of all dexes which I would implement
type ContractNames = "UniswapV2" | "UniswapV3" | ...;

// This "mapping" handles contract names to its swap method hendlers as for UniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensHandler
const contractMethodsImplementations: Partial<Record<ContractNames, ContractMethodImplementations>> = {
  UniswapV2: {
    swapExactETHForTokensHandler: UniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensHandler,
    // Other methods
  },
  // Other dexes if needed in future
};
```

But now I do not have all implementations and still want to specify that some keys of `contractMethodsImplementations` could be not defined, but if that specific key is defined, I could get it methods without undefined errors as such:

```js
if (contractMethodsImplementations[contractType]) {
    contractMethodsImplementations[contractType][methodName];
  }

// contractMethodsImplementations[contractType] - Object is possibly undefined
```

It seems, that my approach of full `Partial` `Record` said typescript that all properties of `contractMethodsImplementations` could be undefined.

As a result, I want to create such method to find specific swap method handler by its contract name and method name to handle:

```js
export function methodFinder(
  tx: TransactionResponse,
  contractType: ContractNames,
  abi: InterfaceAbi,
  decodedData: TransactionDescription,
): FinderOutput {
  const { name: methodName, args: methodArgs, value: inputValue } = decodedData;

  if (contractMethodsImplementations[contractType]) {
    contractMethodsImplementations[contractType][methodName];
    // And pass arguments somehow to requested handler with running it and return resulted data
  }
}
```

Is there any approach or event better solution of my problem? Would appreciate any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the new "satisfies" operator that prevents a type cast of all properties?

```
const contractMethodsImplementations = {
  UniswapV2: {
    swapExactETHForTokensHandler: UniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensHandler,
    // Other methods
  },
  // Other dexes if needed in future
} satisfies Partial<Record<ContractNames, ContractMethodImplementations>>;
```

Comment: With that approach I get an error in `methodFinder` that is about the key in `contractMethodsImplementations `, so `contractType: ContractNames` could not be as key for `contractMethodsImplementations`. Anyway, thank you for paying attention, I will check this operator further, may it would help me